# Ambiguous tag: script

Tags: discussion

Which is the intent of the [script](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) tag? Automation/scripting, or the script for a film? I see it being used for both and there is no tag description that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a good point.

I'd suggest we use [script](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) for a film script, and [scripting](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) for automation related questions.

Thoughts?

Comment: We would probably want more disambiguation though.  I think something more like film-script and automation-scripting might be more clear.

Comment: Good call. I'd support that.